# Substitute for <c:set> in JSF Facelets

Tags: jsf, jstl

In JSTL I used to use  to store some temporary data when this data comes from a field of the MBean that is expensive to call( field that is binded to a DAO call, for instance). 
a little example:

```
<c:set var="total" value="${someMBean.total}" >
<c:if test="${total > 0}" >
  do this...
</c:if>
<c:if test="${total <= 0}" >
  do that...
</c:if>
```

In JSF facelet I use "rendered" instead of JSTL  but I still need to store the data temporarily in order to avoid many calls. I can't mix both jstl and jsf facelets for this reasons [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense?

][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) . How could I do that using facelets?

Comment: My question is not a duplicate. I need to know if there is any subtitute for <c:set> in JSF facelets.